# Optimizing a linear functional over nested sets

Tags: continuity, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $F_0\supseteq F_1\supseteq F_2\supseteq\cdots$ be a sequence of nested closed convex sets in $\mathbb{R}^d$ with some $d\ge 1$. Assume that $0\in F_n$ for all $n\ge 0$. Let $a\in\mathbb{R}^d$ be a vector and set $F_\infty:=\cap_{n=0}^\infty F_n$. I wonder whether or not
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{n\uparrow\infty}\sup_{x\in F_n}\{a\cdot x\}=\sup_{x\in F_\infty}\{a\cdot x\}.
\end{equation*}
I am looking for a formal proof. Clearly, $\lim_{n\uparrow\infty}\sup_{x\in F_n}\{a\cdot x\}\ge\sup_{x\in F_\infty}\{a\cdot x\}$, so that the point is to discuss the opposite bound. One can easily show that $\lim_{n\uparrow\infty}\sup_{x\in F_n}\{a\cdot x\}\le\sup_{x\in F_\infty}\{a\cdot x\}$ if the sets $F_n$ are compact. What can we say when compactness is not assumed?

Answer (score 1):

Without compactness, this is no longer true. Let $d = 2$,
$$
F_n = \{x \in \mathbb R^2 \mid x_1 \in [0,1] \;\text{and}\; x_2 \ge n x_1 \}.
$$
Then,
$$F_\infty = \{x \in \mathbb R^2 \mid x_1 = 0 \;\text{and}\; x_2 \ge 0\}.$$

Finally, we can choose $a = (1,0)$. Due to $(1,n) \in F_n$, we have
$$\sup_{x \in F_n} a \cdot x = 1$$
for all $n$, but
$$\sup_{x \in F_\infty} a \cdot x = 0.$$

Comment: Yes, you are right.